# Get specific records in an ordered data by time but doesn't have primary key for association

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, the title isn't enough to explain the problem. I have the following data which gives the time and length of iron bars. There is no primary key that identifies each iron bar. However, the data is ordered by time and whenever the length is zero we know that the values after it belong to the same iron bar. The time is when the measurement is recorded, and length is the measurement. Here is the script to create the data:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ([time] DATETIME, [length] FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES ('2023-01-15 01:00:10', 0), ('2023-01-15 02:23:15', 0), ('2023-01-15 02:23:16', 0.3334), ('2023-01-15 02:23:23', 1.11), ('2023-01-15 02:23:50', 2.225), ('2023-01-15 02:24:00', 5), ('2023-01-15 02:24:13', 5.334), ('2023-01-15 02:24:23', 5.9), ('2023-01-15 02:24:35', 6.125), ('2023-01-15 02:25:30', 6.334), ('2023-01-15 02:26:33', 7.996), ('2023-01-15 02:27:31', 10.3), ('2023-01-15 02:27:32', 0), ('2023-01-15 02:28:28', 0), ('2023-01-15 02:29:22', 0), ('2023-01-15 02:30:14', 0.66669), ('2023-01-15 02:30:15', 1.669), ('2023-01-15 02:30:25', 2.334), ('2023-01-15 02:30:30', 3), ('2023-01-15 02:30:35', 5.669), ('2023-01-15 02:30:56', 6.669), ('2023-01-15 02:31:15', 7.332), ('2023-01-15 02:31:30', 8), ('2023-01-15 02:31:40', 9.5), ('2023-01-15 02:31:44', 9.9), ('2023-01-15 02:31:55', 10), ('2023-01-15 02:32:15', 10.4), ('2023-01-15 02:32:20', 0), ('2023-01-15 02:32:30', 0.5), ('2023-01-15 02:32:44', 1), ('2023-01-15 02:32:54', 1.334)
```

What I'm trying to get from this data are the records when the length becomes 0, 5, 7 and 10. Usually, the length is not a whole number and has a fraction. In that case I'll take the first length close to the whole number. For example, If I have the following lengths: 4.9, 5.33, 5.5, 5.7, then I'll take the value 5.33 because it is the least number higher than 5. The same applies for the remaining lengths.

Number 0 indicates a new Iron bar, but it also can be recorded more than once for the same Bar. Here is a screenshot of the data above:
[3 iron bars with lengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mjM8.png)
And this is the data I'm trying to get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no6wF.png)

I tried the following but this leads to data to get scrambled. Just added this since stackoverflow requests it but obviously not what I'm looking for.

```
SELECT MIN([time]), FLOOR([length])
FROM @data
WHERE FLOOR([length]) IN (0, 5, 7, 10)
GROUP BY FLOOR([length])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Posting images of your sample data and desired output is not very helpful. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Comment: You probably want to take a peek at LEAD/LAG functions for this.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @SeanLange Thx for the Why bit about not using images..

Comment: The images I used are for explanation since somethings are not easy to explain in writing and the images are not for code / text to be copied!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool question, appeared much more complicated then it seems to be :)

```
;with candidates as (
    select 
        *
    from @data 
    where floor([length]) in (0, 5, 7, 10)
)
, candidatesWithPrevLength as (
    select 
        *
        , lag([length]) over (order by [time]) as lengthPrevious
    from candidates     
), candidatesWithGroupStarts as (
    select
        *
        , case when [length] < lengthPrevious or lengthPrevious is null then 1 else null end as 'groupStart'
    from candidatesWithPrevLength
), groups as (
    select
        [time]
        , lead([time]) over (order by [time]) as validUntil
        , row_number() over (order by [time]) as groupId
    from candidatesWithGroupStarts  
    where groupStart = 1
), candidatesInGroups as (
    select 
        c.* 
        , g.groupId
    from candidates c, groups g
    where c.[time] >= g.[time] and (c.[time] < g.validUntil or g.validUntil is null)
), candidatesInGroupsWithOrders as (
    select 
        * 
        , row_number() over (partition by groupId, floor([length]) order by [time]) as OrderNo
    from candidatesInGroups
)
select [time], [length] from candidatesInGroupsWithOrders where orderno = 1
```

Surprisingly, I had to use a bunch of SQL mechanisms to achieve this goal: CTE-s, join, window functions

Will try to describe the idea in brief:

- find candidate bars (ones who match initial conditions)
- calculate groups of candidates (based on 0-to-10 length checks)
- split all candidates into groups
- select needed bars from these groups

That's just a possible option. Definitely, a bit "dirty". Not sure how it will work with huge amounts of data. Definitely could be simplified and optimized. But it works and could be a good "starting point"

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly on the data set I provided. .Now I have to try it on a bigger data set and I believe it will work. Then I will have to study your solution to learn from it... Can't say, "Thanks" enough.